# Determine if Monitor is off

Tags: 11.04, monitor

How do I determine the state of my Monitor in Ubuntu 11.04. I've seen a lot of stuff regarding dpms, but for what ever reason, I don't have the dpms module running on my ubuntu install and I'd really rather not go messing with my xorg.conf file if I can help it.

Comment: Can you get us the output of `cat /proc/acpi/button/power/PWRB/info` and `cat /proc/acpi/button/power/PWRF/info`?

Comment: See also: [Check if display is powered on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733629/check-if-display-is-powered-on) on Stack Overflow

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,